# Grails 2.2.0 Support in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am trying to create a grails 2.2.0 project using eclipse-jee-juno. It gives me an error

*Groovy compiler level expected by the project does not match workspace compiler level. 
Project compiler level is: 1.8.X
Workspace compiler level is 1.7.X
Go to Project properties -> Groovy compiler to set the Groovy compiler level for this project.*

**Background**: I have installed grails 2.2.0 and I am able to create and run a sample project/controller by using the **command** line (not eclipse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grails 2.x need groovy 1.8+ to work. In eclipse, right click your project, select 'properties' from menu and go to Groovy compiler, select groovy version 1.8.xxxx. Or you can go to 'preference' menu and change the global setting for groovy compiler version.

Comment: I changed it to 2.0 it gives me a similar error

Groovy compiler level expected by the project does not match workspace compiler level. 
Project compiler level is: 2.0.X
Workspace compiler level is 1.8.X
Go to Project properties -> Groovy compiler to set the Groovy compiler level for this project

Comment: Did you try 1.8.x? I think the error message is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The reason I chose 2.0 because grails is supposed to work with Groovy 2.0. 

Having said that I changed it to 1.8 and it got rid of the compilation error, but when I try to run it - it gives me the following runtime error 


Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : null

Comment: This is another problem. Refer to [the jira](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3128) which provides a potential workaround:  `go into your grails 2.2.RC4 installation directory and copy the contents of '/lib/org.springsource.springloaded' into 'lib/com.springsource.springloaded'.`

Comment: Why don't they make it clear on grails.org that Grails 2.x requires Groovy 1.8 and will not work with Groovy 2.x ?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps that enabled me to run the application on grails 2.2.0.

> 1. Install **JDK** 7
> 2. Install **Grails 2.2.0**
> 3. Install **eclipse-jee-juno** or **GGTS**
> 4. Download **grails-2.2.0.RC4**
> 5. Under **GRAILS_HOME\lib**, Create a directory **com.springsource.springloaded** with a *subdirectory* **springloaded-core**
> 6. Copied contents of **RC4\lib\org.springsource.springloaded** into **com.springsource.springloaded**

*Restart* GGTS or Eclipse. Your GRAILS app should be up and running!