# Issues with upgrade to Grails 2.2.0 using GGTS

Tags: grails

I’m trying to upgrade Grails to version 2.2.0. I used [gvm](http://gvmtool.net) and installed Grails 2.2.0. After this I changed my project in [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts) to use Grails version 2.2.0 and Groovy version 2.0.0. But when I finally tried to run the project, I got the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VMError opening zip file or JAR manifest
missing : null

agent library failed to init: instrument
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I started using Grails 2.2.0 - The solution Ian mentioned works, here is the link to the issue and resolution that occurred in my project

[Grails 2.2.0 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189786/grails-2-2-0-support-in-eclipse)

Added on 1/15/2013 Other suggestions based on 2.2.0/ivy cache issues

I am running on windows, a couple of things to try.

1. Based on your error message seems like the issue might be related to the **Ivy** cached, I would suggest cleaning that out using the **clean command.**
2. I would also go ahead and delete the Icy cache folders on your machine at **\ivy-cache**(after backing it up just in case)
3. Read grails documentation at  **http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0/guide/gettingStarted.html**, refer to **section 2.3** regarding Ivy cache – there might be issues running 2.x and 1.x grails projects side by side.
4. When install, I do not have to install groovy explicitly - I just install grails and that take care of the groovy code implicitly. Is that possible for you to do? To rule out dependency issues?
5. On my version of grails I have the groovy version showing up as **2.0.5** – I assume you meant **grails 2.2.0** – can you ensure that you have a groovy version installed with is compatible with grails 2.2.0?
6. If possible try your code on a fresh device where grails has not been installed before. This is to rule out interference due to other existing issues

Comment: I got the following error: Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script RunApp: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/ChainResolver (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: What is your environment specs win/unix,groovy version, If you give me the steps - I can try reproducing the issue on my system.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X Lion and groovy 2.2.0.

Comment: Added edits to original post related to ivy cache and other possible troubleshooting methods

Comment: The differences between our dev systems are the operating systems (mine win), JDK 7 (yours 6)- If I find the time, I will try installing JDK6 to see if I get the same error. 

Questions.
Did you clear the ivy cache? and try if so what is the outcome. 
Are you using sts/ggts or is it command line grails.
Are you on a system which already has the older version of grails installed?

Comment: I'm using ggts. I cleared Ivy cache folder. I have an older version of grails on my system.I tried to run the app from command line but got a weird error: grails_app_views_index_gsp: 71: expecting ')', found 'public' @ line 71, column 1. public static final Map JSP_TAGS = new HashMap() ^ 1 error . While it was working before without errors.

Comment: At this point my suggestion would be to troubleshoot at which specific point the application is failing e.g. create a new app run, add a controller run, add a domain class run - that might help you troubleshoot. 

I assume you have run the grails -version, javac -version to ensure your settings point to  the 2.2.0 dir and JDK dir appropriately. Also ensure that your JAVA_HOME, GRAILS_HOME are set correctly.

Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189786/grails-2-2-0-support-in-eclipse- I faced this issue when initially running against grails 2.2.0

Answer (score 7):

We had the same problem.
This is due to eclipse saving old run configuration for the previous grails version.

Just remove old launch configuration and retry.

To remove old launch configuration : 
go to Run\RunConfiguration\Grails
select all nodes and remove them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3141) to do with the fact that the version of the springloaded reloading agent used by 2.2 (and 2.1.3) has a different name from that used by previous versions of Grails.  There's a workaround in the bug report, or you can upgrade to a nightly build of GGTS which knows about the new name (as described in [this bug report](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3134)).

Answer (score 1):

I am using GGTS 3.2 with Groovy compiler 2.1.1 on Windows XP.

Had imported a project from GGTS 3.1, upgraded compiler to 2.1.1 and got in mess, so
deleted the project and removed it from .grails cache, then re-created project from scratch. When it came to running the project I got the ivy error.

Removing the old launch configuration via Run->RunConfiguration...Grails fixed problem without switching to a night build of GGTS.

(BTW Deleting ivy-cache didn't help at all)