# Incompatible groovy compiler version

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have grails-2.2.0 installed on Mac OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion) and I am using Groovy-Grails-Tool-Suite with grails and Java installed correctly. However, when I create a new Grails Project, I get a message saying -

```
Some projects in your workspace use Grails 2.20 

You are using the Groovy 1.8.6.xx-20120921-2000-e43RELEASE compiler.

Grails requires version range 2.0.0

Various functionality may break if you use an incompatible compiler.

Set Preferences >> Groovy >> Compiler to change the compiler version.
```

Has anyone else encountered this. I am using GGTS based on Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189786/grails-2-2-0-support-in-eclipse/14189867#14189867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Groovy Compiler from Dashboard/Extensions in GGTS and change compiler under Window -> Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler to 2.x